# Rails: How to build an association dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I build an association dynamically? For example:

```
current_customer.company.association(:tenders).order('created_at DESC')
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? ActiveRecord assumes your data model isn't constantly changing shape...

Comment: I'm building service layer for my app. So I need a base service class for handle CRUD something like below example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to pass in the association to some other method.  What you are looking for there is the send(:method_name, *args)

so it would be

```
passed_in_association = :tenders
if( [:tenders,:orders,:users].include?(passed_in_association) )  #for security probably better to add it to a before filter.
 current_customer.company.send(passed_in_association).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

Comment: Note that `send` introduces security concerns, even without arguments, if the input can come from something outside your application. Try `42.send(:exit!)` for one such example.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. But @willglynn noted it's have a security concerns.

Comment: Yes you would want to make sure that users can't just pass in anything via an API or HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do but you can just use `send` if you want to use a variable to access an association (it's just another method after all):

```
current_customer.company.send(:tenders).order('created_at DESC')
```